# Actionscript How to debug using getStackTrace() in any web browser, not in flash player without the browser

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex4, flex3

How to debug using getStackTrace() in any web browser, not in flash player without the browser

```
trace2(err.getStackTrace());
```

I'am trying to get the error stackTrace in my broswer, but it returns `NULL`, according to the documentation the stack trace is only displayed in the flash player debugger, but I need to see it in the browser, cause many data is passed through web server, is there any browsers or addons who can help me to see the stackTrace?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the [Flash Player content debugger plugin](http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html), with that you'll be also able to use the debugger for the Flash movies loaded in the browser.